# How create Interface for QObject class

Tags: qt, qt5

I want to create an interface for `QObject` class with signal/slot system.

The code below works but has a disadvantage: Interface inherits `QObject` and has no `Q_OBJECT` macro.

I want to make a pure virtual interface, so `InterfaceClass` shouldn't have a constructor. But in `RealisationClass` I cannot call `QObject` (error: type 'QObject' is not a direct base of 'RealisationClass') nor `InterfaceClass` (It hasn't constructor `InterfaceClass(QObject* parent)`) constructors. Moreover I cannot add `Q_OBJECT` macro in `InterfaceClass` (error: undefined reference to 'vtable' for InterfaceClass')

So, how should I change classes to add `QObject()` constructor in `RealisationClass` and add `Q_OBJECT` macro (or remove `QObject` inheritance) to InterfaceClass.

IntefaceClass.h:

```cpp
#ifndef INTERFACE_CLASS_H
#define INTERFACE_CLASS_H
#include <QObject>

class InterfaceClass : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
 public:
  virtual ~InterfaceClass(){};
  virtual void foo() = 0;
};
Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(InterfaceClass, "Interface")
#endif // INTERFACE_CLASS_H
```

RealisationClass.h:

```cpp
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>

#include "InterfaceClass.h"

class RealisationClass : public InterfaceClass {
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_INTERFACES(InterfaceClass)
 public:
    explicit RealisationClass(QObject* parent = nullptr){};
    void foo() override {qDebug() << "Hello, world";};
};
```

main.cpp:

```cpp
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include "RealisationClass.h"
#include "InterfaceClass.h"
#include <QObject>
#include <QTimer>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QTimer everySecondTimer;
    everySecondTimer.setInterval(1000);
    QScopedPointer<InterfaceClass> interfacePointer(new RealisationClass);
    QObject::connect(&everySecondTimer, &QTimer::timeout, interfacePointer.get(), &InterfaceClass::foo);
    everySecondTimer.start();
    return a.exec();
}
```

---

#### Edit

Q_OBJECT macro problem has another reason: I don't add InterfaceClass.h as target to Cmake's AUTOMOC (qmake (moc) didn't handle this file).

Comment: Which version of qt are you using? Works for me for **Qt 5.15** and **Qt 5.9**. Please, try running `qmake` before building. Also, you don't need to use **Q_OBJECT** macro in the `RealisationClass`

Comment: @Alloces Yeah, this is working code (I'am using Qt 5.12.9). But i can't call QObject(parent) constructor from RealisationClass. It worries me. About Q_OBJECT: "We strongly recommend the use of this macro in all subclasses of QObject regardless of whether or not they actually use signals, slots and properties, since failure to do so may lead certain functions to exhibit strange behavior." from here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html

Comment: Yes, I understood that you need to call the **QObject(parent)** constructor. And it is strange behavior - I can create your `RealisationClass` with `auto *r = new RealisationClass(myQObject)` without any problem.  And about **Q_OBJECT** - this is recommended when you inherit from the *QObject* class, but you inherit from the **QObject** inheritor class. For this case, I think, the most appropriate solution would be not inherit your `InterfaceClass` from **QObject**.

Comment: Does `InterfaceClass` need to be a `QObject`? What if `RealisationClass` used multiple inheritance to derive from both `InterfaceClass` and `QObject`?

Comment: I think yes, because of i want have a possibility to change 'QScopedPointer<InterfaceClass> interfacePointer(**new RealisationClass**);' to 'QScopedPointer<InterfaceClass> interfacePointer(**new AnotherImplementationOfInterfaceClass**);' and connect will be still working, As i understood there is a general advantage of using interfaces. I created class like @Dean Johnson says. But there is still some problems with signals. I think best way - create new question about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using interfaces with `QObject` hierarchies is a real pain. You often want your interface to have some features of `QObject` (ie. signals/slots, destroyed signal, integrates with Qt APIs) but have it be a lightweight interface definition. Unless Qt is refactored so that an `IQObject` exists that is used throughout the Qt code-base, you can't get a perfect solution. What I recommend is to simply forward all constructor calls through to `QObject`:

```
#ifndef INTERFACE_CLASS_H
#define INTERFACE_CLASS_H
#include <QObject>

class InterfaceClass : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
 public:
  using QObject::QObject; // <<--------

  virtual ~InterfaceClass(){};
  virtual void foo() = 0;
};
Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(InterfaceClass, "Interface")
#endif // INTERFACE_CLASS_H
```

With the `using QObject::QObject` line, `InterfaceClass` now has constructors with the same declarations as `QObject`. All they do is forward the call to `QObject`. With that, you can now do this in `RealisationClass`:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>

#include "InterfaceClass.h"

class RealisationClass : public InterfaceClass {
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_INTERFACES(InterfaceClass)
 public:
    explicit RealisationClass(QObject* parent = nullptr)
      : InterfaceClass(parent) // <<------
    {};
    void foo() override {qDebug() << "Hello, world";};
};
```

This has two major downsides:

1. Your interface is no longer a true interface because of the constructors.
2. Your derived classes cannot inherit from multiple interfaces designed this way (diamond inheritance).

I still need to play around with virtual inheritance (`class InterfaceClass : public virtual QObject`) to see if that can solve #2 without introducing other issues.

Comment: Did you solve signals in interface problem? As i understood there is no way to create virtual one (https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-41004). So if you add signal to interface you cannot add it in RealisationClass declaration.

Comment: In my case i created non-virtual signals both in InterfaceClass and ReleaseClass. There are 2 different signals - it leads to erros. To avoid errors i connect ReleaseClasses signal to InterfaceClasses signal in ReleaseClass constructor.

Comment: Don't make them virtual - just put the signal directly in the interface. Because the signal is generated by `moc` you don't need to ever define it. Also, there would never be any reason to override the signal like what you usually do with virtual methods in an interface. With the signal in the interface, you don't have to put anything for the signal in the derived class.